# I want to apply a modification to the path environement system variable without rebooting or restarting the cmd owing to c#

Tags: c#, oracle, environment-variables, installshield

I am using a C# dll which I am using from Installshield to add path of Oracle to the Path environement system variable to be able to connect to Oracle database owing to the instant client.

Whan I run the installer first time it doesn't succeed but make the change to the path variable. It succeed on the second try because the path is already changed from the first run.
So the conclusion is that the Oracle database provider does not view the change directly after modifying it with code.

I want a way to detect that changes to the path variable without the need to try the installation a second time.

```
var ancientPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine); 

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", ancientPath + ";" + tmp, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Comment: var ancientPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
       
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", ancientPath + ";" + tmp, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is explicitly not do-able.  A process can modify it's own environment, and it can spawn processes with different environments, but no process can change the environment of another process.  When you launch a new process after the first installation, you should see the updated path.

If you want an existing process to use the new environment variables, it must be restarted.  If your installer is failing because it's missing path information, you're going to have to work around that.

Comment: I tried to create an OracleConnection just after modifying the path variable in the same method, I suppose that means it is in the same process, isn't it? and when I do log the new path value I find it changed but unfortunately the new instance of OracleConnection fail, however it pass when I relaunch the whole setup not just the method call.

Comment: Is there a way  maybe to propagate that change to the parent process?

Comment: What exactly does "fail" mean here?

Comment: fail mean that it requitre an oracle client installed, pass means it does not require a client installed but use an instant client whose dll are located in the path which I am adding to the path system variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending **WM_SETTINGCHANGE** message to all windows, as stated in the [following MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011).

> SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
>       (LPARAM) "Environment", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
>       5000, &dwReturnValue);